# Why is 'cmd' not recognized in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute batch script on Jenkins on Windows agent, but I see the below error in a declarative pipeline in Jenkins, can someone please advise.

```
[Pipeline] bat
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I added also `C:\Windows\System32` in Jenkins Windows agent environment variable.

```
environment{
    CREATE = "call C:\\IBM\\InformationServer11_3\\Clients\\Classic\\dsadmin.exe"
  }

stage('create project'){
        steps {
            script{
               echo 'Creating Project..'
                {
               bat "${CREATE} -domain ${BUILD_SERVER}:9443
```

This is the output of `set path` executed in a command prompt window:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin64;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin\X11;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\mksnt;C:\IBM\InformationSever_117/jdk32\jre\bin;C:\IBM\InformationServer_117/jdk32\jre\bin\j9vm;C:\IBM\InformationServer_117\ASBNode\lib\cpp;C:\IBM\InformationServer_117\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MTdll\bin;D:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin;D:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin;D:\cygwin64\bin;C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\jdk32\jre\bin;C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\jdk32\jre\bin\j9vm;C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\ASBNode\lib\cpp;C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cppvc60\MT_dll\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\net-snmp\bin;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;/occ/cmg/build/encre/trunk/client-server/architecture_linux
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.sh;.ksh;.csh;.sed;.awk;.pl
```

So the list of folder paths in **local** `Path` is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt
C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin64
C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin\X11
C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\mksnt
C:\IBM\InformationSever_117/jdk32\jre\bin
C:\IBM\InformationServer_117/jdk32\jre\bin\j9vm
C:\IBM\InformationServer_117\ASBNode\lib\cpp
C:\IBM\InformationServer_117\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MTdll\bin
D:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin
D:\cygwin64\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin
D:\cygwin64\bin
C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\jdk32\jre\bin
C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\jdk32\jre\bin\j9vm
C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\ASBNode\lib\cpp
C:\IBM\InformationServer11_3\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cppvc60\MT_dll\bin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
D:\net-snmp\bin
D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
/occ/cmg/build/encre/trunk/client-server/architecture_linux
```

Comment: after updating the above four folders in system path on first four, still we see the cmd error while executing using jenkins pipeline

Comment: [Pipeline] bat
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: did you set absolute path for `GRADLE_HOME`?